# What does Docker STOPSIGNAL do?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, signals

I am trying to understand what exactly the `STOPSIGNAL` command in a dockerfile does. So according to the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage):

> The STOPSIGNAL instruction sets the system call signal that will be
>   sent to the container to exit. This signal can be a valid unsigned
>   number that matches a position in the kernel’s syscall table, for
>   instance 9, or a signal name in the format SIGNAME, for instance
>   SIGKILL.

With this explanation I understand that there is some signal that is sent to the docker container to tell inside applications to stop. But when I shutdown a running container with `sudo docker stop container-name`, doesn't it then automatically also stops everything that runs inside? I can type this command without getting any errors. Isn't it then redundant to explicitly define `STOPSIGNAL` inside a dockerfile?

Looking at how [Nginx is built with a dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f603bb3632ea6df0bc9da2179c18eb322c286298/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile#L21), the command `STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM` is used. But what does that exaclty mean? Would it break something to not define `STOPSIGNAL`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`SIGTERM` is the default signal sent to containers to stop them: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

`STOPSIGNAL` does allow you to override the default signal sent to the container. Leaving it out of the Dockerfile causes no harm - it will remain the default of `SIGTERM`.

This being said, it is unclear why the author has explicitly defined the `STOPSIGNAL` as `SIGTERM`.

Looking at this [commit](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/commit/16ec71e7e8452fa28a95d014807f95605c09a8fe), we can see that the `STOPSIGNAL` used to be set to `SIGQUIT`.

My guess is that they left it in explicitly for documentation's sake after making the change.

Discussion of the change here: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/167

Answer (score 26):

When you run [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/), you are instructing the Docker daemon to send a signal to the process running the container to stop.

By default, it does this by sending a `SIGTERM` and then wait a short period so the process can exit gracefully. If the process does not terminate within a grace period (10s by default, customisable), it will send a `SIGKILL`.

However, your application may be configured to listen to a different signal - `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, for example.

In these instances, you can use the `STOPSIGNAL` Dockerfile instruction to override the default.

Comment: To complete this answer, "a short period" means 10s by default. If this is unsuitable, the "grace period" can be set as argument with the docker stop command.

Comment: @VincentPazeller Thank you, what you said is correct. Feel free to edit my answer!